# cannot add bing theme using image overlay

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using this sample to add and image overlay to a bing map in a web app
http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/05/22/image-overlays-with-bing-maps-javascript/
  and is working fine.

Now I need to add pushpins with tooltip, and looks like that I have to add the **Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme** theme.

If I load this module I can't see the image overlay anymore: If I remove the loadModule the image works fine again.
  How can I make work both together?

thanks,
  Luca

Comment: Could your share part of the javascript code where you're using the map control, it will help to understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use mouse events with the pushpin to create your tooltip. That's all the Bing Theme module does. The Bing Theme module overrides all styles and functionality for pushpins to match the Bing Maps consumer site. The image overlay's functionality extends the pushpin class to work, which is why it is not compatible with the Bing Theme module. Generally I don't recommend using the Bing Theme module as it really limits you when it comes to customizations.